# map Jboss to url instead of ip

Tags: jboss

Is it possible to map jboss to a url like "something.nm.com:8555" instead of "192.13.50.999:8555"?

I tried running it as standalone.sh -b something.nm.com:8555 and editing the standalone.xml like so but no luck. Im using JBoss 7

```
<interface name="public">
      <any-address/>
    </interface>
```

Comment: Apparently this is a Network admin stuff so he had to configure something on the network. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You can simply use the command

Assuming you are running on a *nix OS

```
cd $JBOSS_HOME/bin
./standalone.sh -b something.nm.com
```

**NOTE**: The IP address of "something.nm.com" needs to resolve to the IP address of the machine you are running this on otherwise JBoss cannot start as it cannot bind on another machines IP/NIC.

Unfortunately, you cannot specify the port on the command line. You can change the port numbers in `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` or you can create an environment variable in your configuration file and pass that value as a command like parameter. For example: In your configuration file you can set the http port as follows

```
<socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
```

And pass the variable as follows

```
cd $JBOSS_HOME/bin
./standalone.sh -b something.nm.com -Djboss.http.port=8555
```

Again, I am assuming you want the 8555 port to be HTTP port. In any case you can apply the same logic to any port you want to pass through command line.

Hope this helps.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply jBug, i ran ./standalone.sh -b something.nm.com I get Could not get address for host: something.nm.com: java.net.UnknownHostException: something.nm.com The thing is "something.nm.com" is not the machine name/hostname of the server. It is an alias/url that I wish to make as my link to my app. Is there anyway i can link "something.nm.com" as the url of my app

Comment: It looks like something.nm.com is not resolved properly. In that case the easiest *HACK* is to add this your /etc/hosts file. 
`##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1       something.nm.com`

Comment: I just noticed that when i try to run the link on another computer it doesn't show up, meaning i can try this only on my pc. How can i make it so other pc on the network can access it. I tried running -b 0.0.0.0 doesnt work

Comment: Instead of mapping 127.0.0.1 to something.nm.com, map your actual IP in /etc/hosts. For example: If you machine IP is "192.168.1.12" your /etc/hosts should have the entry `192.168.1.12 something.nm.com`. The you can execute `-b yourIP or Domain`

Comment: That's what i did. It will work only if I add the 192.168.1.12 something.nm.com on another PC's etc/host file plus the server's etc/host file. But if i don't it will say page not found.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0`?